# Extending web scraping code to multiple pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a set of products that are displayed on multiple pages. I need to go to each of these pages, and get the details. I wrote the following code but it seems that there is something wrong with the loop as the entries are obtained multiple times.

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while(page <= max_pages):
        url = "https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/?cpapmachines=autocpap&page=" + str(page) + "&redirectCancelled=1&sort=6a"
        product_info_url = 'https://www.respshop.com/product_info.php'
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0'}

        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

        all_data = []
        for item in soup.select('td.name a'):
            sku = item.find_parent('table', class_="prod2_t")
                .select_one('b:contains("SKU:")')
                .find_next('td').text
            print(item.text, sku)
            products_id = re.search(r'p-(\d+)\.html', item['href'])[1]

            s = BeautifulSoup(
                requests.post(
                    product_info_url,
                    data={'products_id': products_id,
                          'tab': 3},
                    headers=headers).content,
                'html.parser')

            row = {'Name': item.text, 'SKU': sku, 'URL': item['href']}
            for k, v in zip(s.select('#cont_3 td.main:nth-child(1)'),
                    s.select('#cont_3 td.main:nth-child(2)')):
                row[k.get_text(strip=True)] = v.get_text(strip=True)
            all_data.append(row)

        df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
        df.to_csv('ACPAP.csv')
    page += 1
    
cpap_spider(3)
```

Comment: You need to increment the `page` variable inside the while loop

Comment: I really want to downvote you for the image of a "cpap spider" that I'll never stop worrying about now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    page=1
    while(page<=max_pages):
        url= "https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/?cpapmachines=autocpap&page="+str(page)+"&redirectCancelled=1&sort=6a"
        product_info_url = 'https://www.respshop.com/product_info.php'
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0'}

        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

        all_data = []
        for item in soup.select('td.name a'):
            sku = item.find_parent('table', class_="prod2_t").select_one('b:contains("SKU:")').find_next('td').text
            print(item.text, sku)
            products_id = re.search(r'p-(\d+)\.html', item['href'])[1]

            s = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(product_info_url, data={'products_id': products_id, 'tab': 3}, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

            row = {'Name': item.text, 'SKU': sku, 'URL': item['href']}
            for k, v in zip(s.select('#cont_3 td.main:nth-child(1)'),
                    s.select('#cont_3 td.main:nth-child(2)')):
                row[k.get_text(strip=True)] = v.get_text(strip=True)
            all_data.append(row)
        page+=1

    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    df.to_csv('ACPAP.csv')
    
    
cpap_spider(3)
```

Output:

```
ResMed AirMini Auto Travel CPAP Machine with Optional FREE Mask 38113
ResMed AirSense 10 AutoSet CPAP with HumidAir 37207, 37208
Respironics DreamStation Go Auto Travel CPAP Machine w/ Bluetooth DSG500S11, DSG500H11
Fisher & Paykel SleepStyle Auto CPAP SPSAAU, SPSABU
Respironics DreamStation Auto CPAP Machine DSX500T11, DSX500H11, ...
SoClean CPAP Sanitizer and Cleaner SC1200
HDM Z2 Travel Auto CPAP Machine 718116
Transcend 3 miniCPAP Auto 503104
Transcend 365 miniCPAP Auto w/ Humidifier 503091
APEX Medical XT Auto Travel CPAP Machine SF04101
Devilbiss IntelliPAP AutoAdjust CPAP Machine with Optional Heated Humidifier DV54D-HH
Devilbiss IntelliPAP 2 AutoAdjust CPAP Machine DV64D, DV64D-HH, ...
ResMed AirSense 10 AutoSet CPAP for Her with HumidAir 37209, 37210
APEX Medical XT Auto CPAP Machine with Heated Humidifier SC04201
APEX Medical iCH II Auto CPAP Machine with Humidifier SF07109
Respironics PR System One Auto CPAP Machine & Humidifier For Sale DS560TS, DS560HS, ...
HDM Z1 Auto Travel CPAP Machine HD60-1007, HD60-1017
Fisher & Paykel ICON+ Auto CPAP Machine with Built In Heated Humidifier & SensAwake ICONAAN-HT, ICONAAN
Transcend Auto Portable CPAP with EZEX Pressure Relief 503065
ResMed AirStart 10 Auto CPAP w/ Humidifier 37202
...
...
..
```

Page 1 CSV:

```
,Name,SKU,URL,HCPCS Code,Bluetooth,Compliance Meter,Data Storage Capacity,Data Viewing,Flex Modes,Flex Pressure Relief,Humidifier,Operation Modes,Power,Power Consumption,Sound Pressure Level,Water Chamber Capacity,Modes,Pressure Range,Ramp Time,Starting Ramp Pressure,Dimensions,Dimensions w Hum,Weight,Weight of machine with Power Supply,Weight with Humidifier,Pressure Relief,Sound/Noise Level,Humidifier Included,Altitude Adjustment,AC Power Supply Weight,Smartphone App,Color,Warranty,Data Card,AC Power,DC Compatible,Extra Features,SmartStart,Machine Language Display,AirView,MyAir,Built-in Cellular Technology,Ramp,Filters,Output,Qtube Included,Auto Start/Stop,Leak Compensation,Z-Breathe,AC Power Supply,Maximum Output Power,Pressure Limit,Comfort Technology,Humidifier Settings,Effective Bluetooth Range,Advanced Event Detection,Rainout Reduction,Battery Recharge,Battery Duration
0,ResMed AirMini Auto Travel CPAP Machine with Optional FREE Mask,38113,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/resmed-airmini-auto-travel-cpap-machine-free-mask-p-1159.html,E0601,Yes,N/A,Onboard,AirMini App for iOS/Android,N/A,N/A,HumidX & HumidX Plus Heat Moisture Exchangers (HME),"CPAP, AutoSet/AutoSet for Her","100-240V, 50-60Hz, Auto Sensing","6.3 Watts, 27 Watts Peak",30 dBA,N/A,"CPAP, AutoSet/AutoSet for Her",4-20 CM H2O,0 to 45 Minutes,4 to Minimum Therapy Pressure,5.4 x 3.3 x 2.1 inches,N/A,10.6 Ounces,11.1 lbs,N/A,"Off, 1, 2, 3 cm H2O",30 dBA,N/A,Automatic Up To 8500 Feet,.5 Pounds or 8 Ounces,AirMini App (iOS or Android),White,2 years,On-Board,"AC power 100-240V, 50-60Hz (Auto Sensing)","Yes, Battery is available separately","Setup kits for F20, N20 and P10 mask",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,ResMed AirSense 10 AutoSet CPAP with HumidAir,"37207, 37208",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/resmed-airsense-10-autoset-cpap-with-humidair-p-846.html,E0601,,,SD Card (Optional) 365 Days of Summary Data,On Screen Sleep Report MyAir,,,Built-in,"CPAP, APAP","100-240 VAC, 50/60 Hz",53 Watts Typical; 104 Watts Peak,26.6 dBA,380 mL to Maximum Fill Line,CPAP + APAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 minute (5 minute increments),4 to Min Pressure (User adjustable),4.57 x 10.04 x 5.91 inches,10.04 x 4.57 x 5.91 inches,2.45 lbs,90w (4.04 lbs),2.75 lbs,"EPR - levels 1 - 3, 1 is the minimum pressure relief and 3 is the maximum",26.6 dBA,Yes,Automatic Up To 8500 Feet,1.30 Lbs,myAir,Black,2-Year Manufacturer Warranty,SD Card,100v-240v (50-60Hz),"Yes, Battery is available separately",Compatible with all masks,Yes,"English, French, Spanish, Portuguese",Yes,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,Respironics DreamStation Go Auto Travel CPAP Machine w/ Bluetooth,"DSG500S11, DSG500H11",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/respironics-dreamstation-auto-travel-cpap-machine-bluetooth-p-1176.html,E0601,Yes,Breathing detection,MicroSD card (optional): lifetime,"On Screen Sleep Report, DreamMapper App (Optional)","C-Flex, C-Flex+, A-Flex",1 to 3,,"CPAP, APAP","100-240 VAC, 50/60 Hz","100 to 240 VAC, 50/60 Hz, 2.0-1.0 A",30.7 dBA,"240 ml. Distilled, Tap, or bottled.",CPAP + APAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 min (5-min increments),"Patient adjustable, Smart Ramp",5.9 x 5.9 x 2.3 inches (15 cm L x 15 cm W x 5.8 cm H),11.6 x 5.9 x 2.3 in.,1.9 lbs (844 g),,"2.62 lbs [CPAP 0.844 g (1.86 lb), Hum - 344.7 g (0.76 lb)]","C-Flex, C-Flex+, A-Flex (Settings = None, 1, 2, 3)",30.7 dBA,Optional,"2286 m (7500'), Automatic",N/A,DreamMapper App available for IOS and Android device,White,"2 years for each CPAP, Humidifier",Lifetime on Optional MicroSD Data Card; Over 1-Year On-Board.,"Universal AC power 100-240V, 50/60Hz (Auto Sensing)",Optional Integrated Overnight Battery Pack,Compatible with all standard Cpap masks,,"English, Spanish",,,,0 to 45 min (5-min increments),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,Fisher & Paykel SleepStyle Auto CPAP,"SPSAAU, SPSABU",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/fisher-paykel-sleepstyle-auto-cpap-p-1238.html,"E0601, E0562",Yes,,"The InfoUSB will store up to 5 years of summary efficacy data, 365 days of detailed efficacy data and 140 hours of high-resolution pressure, leak and flow data.","Without an InfoUSB, the device’s internal memory is capable of storing up to 1 year of summary efficacy data, 30 days of detailed efficacy data and 20 hours of high-resolution pressure, leak and flow data.",,,,"CPAP, APAP",,,,380 ml up to the maximum water level line,,4 to 20 cm H2O,,CPAP mode is 4 cm H20; APAP mode is minimum pressure,144 H x 177 W x 183 D mm (5.6 H x 6.9 W x 7.2 D in),,1.7 kg (3.7 lb). Packed weight (max.): 2.7 kg (5.9 lb),,,,28.0 ± 1.5 dBA,,,,,Black,2-Year Manufacturer Warranty,,"AC power 100-240V, 50-60Hz (Auto Sensing)",,,,"English, French, Italian, Japanese, Chinese(Simple), Chinese(Traditional), Greek, Spanish, Finnish, Polish, Russian, Turkey, German, Arabic, Nederlands, Norwegian, Portuguese, Swedish, Danish",,,,Fixed 20 Minute Duration with SensAwake,Yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,Respironics DreamStation Auto CPAP Machine,"DSX500T11, DSX500H11, ...",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/respironics-dreamstation-auto-cpap-machine-p-990.html,"E0601, E0562, A4604",,N/A,More than 1-Year on SD Data Card; Under 6-Months On-Board.,"On Screen Sleep Report, DreamMapper App (Optional)","C-Flex, C-Flex+, A-Flex (Settings = None, 1, 2, 3)","Settings = None, 1, 2, 3",Integrated DreamStation Humidifier,"CPAP, APAP","100 to 240 VAC, 50/60 Hz, 2.0-1.0 A","100 to 240 VAC, 50/60 Hz, 2.0-1.0 A",25.8 dB(A) machine only/27.9 dB(A) with hum,325 ml,CPAP + APAP,4-20 cmH2O,"0-45 min, Ramp/SmartRamp",4 cm to minimum therapy pressure,7.6 x 6.2 x 3.3 inches,11.7 x 7.6 x x 3.3 inches,1.60 lbs,1.98 kg (4.37 lbs),4.30 lbs,"C-Flex, C-Flex+, A-Flex",26 dBA,Yes,Automatic,Yes,DreamMapper,White with light grey,2 Year Manufacturer Warranty,SD Card,100v to 240v (50-60Hz),Yes,Compatible with all masks,,"English, Spanish",,,,,Reusable pollen and disposable ultra-fine,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,SoClean CPAP Sanitizer and Cleaner,SC1200,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/soclean-cpap-sanitizer-and-cleaner-p-738.html,E1399,,,,,,,,,"100-240 VAC, 50-60 Hz",,,,,,,,"7.5 x 6.5 x 8.5 in (Chamber 7.5 x 4.5 x 5.0 in, Volume = 178 Cubic in)",,5.6 lbs,,,,,,,,,White,2-year limited warranty,,Universal 100v-240v (50-60Hz),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,HDM Z2 Travel Auto CPAP Machine,718116,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/hdm-travel-auto-cpap-machine-p-1312.html,"E0601, A7037, A7038",Yes,,,,,,Waterless - Heat and Moisture Exchanger capsule,"CPAP, APAP","100-240 VAC, 50/60 Hz",20W (30VA),26 dB,,,4-20 cmH2O,0-45 minutes,4 to Minimum Pressure,6.48 x 3.30 x 2.02 in.,,10.4 oz.,,,,26 dBA,,"Automatic Up To 8000 Feet (2,433m)",,NiteLog App,,2 years,,100v-240v (50-60Hz),,,,,,,,,,10dBm,Yes,Yes,Automatic,"Z-Breathe 1,2, or 3 (1 = Gentle, 2 = Moderate, 3 = Maximum Drop in Pressure at Exhalation)",30W,,,,,,,,,
7,Transcend 3 miniCPAP Auto,503104,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/transcend-minicpap-auto-p-1322.html,E0601,,,,,,,,"CPAP, APAP",,,30 dBA,,,4 to 20 cm H2O,,,7.4 x 3.7 x 3.7 inches,,1.09 lbs,,,,,,,,,,3 years,,"100-240V, 50-60Hz (Auto Sensing)","Yes, overnight and multi-night battery (optional)",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8,Transcend 365 miniCPAP Auto w/ Humidifier,503091,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/transcend-365-minicpap-auto-p-1323.html,E0601,,,30-day machine memory,Events and Time of use/ AHI & Leak Detection,,,,"CPAP, APAP",,20-35 W,,195 mL,"Auto CPAP, Auto CPAP w/Ramp, CPAP",4-20 cmH2O,0 to 45 min. (user adjustable),,7.8 x 3.8 x 4.5 in (19.9 x 9.7 x 11.5 cm),,1.7 lbs (770 gm),,,"EZEX Pressure Relief Settings OFF, 1, 2, 3",30 dBA,,"Auto adjust up to 8,000 ft",,,,2 years,,100-240VAC (50-60Hz),,,,,,,,,Ultra-fine (Disposable),"Power Supply - 19VDC, 2.6 Amp",,,Automatic,,,"20 VDC, 3.25 Amp",30 cm H20,"EZEX, 0 = off, 1=minimum relief, 2=moderate relief, 3=maximum relief",0 Off to 10 Maximum,,,,,
9,APEX Medical XT Auto Travel CPAP Machine,SF04101,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/apex-medical-xt-auto-travel-cpap-machine-p-623.html,E0601,N/A,,"The SD card holds 730 sessions of summary data and 18 sessions of efficacy data (AHI, Leak)",User and physician access through any port that accommodates a traditional SD card,,,XT Heated Humidifier Optional,Continuous Positive Airway Pressure (CPAP),"Auto Adjusting Voltage from 100-240V AC, 50-60Hz, Universal Power supply",,28 dBA,"5.1 oz (450 ml), will last 8 hours per night. Note: any excess mask or system leakage will deplete water amount",CPAP and Auto CPAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 minute (@ 5-minute increments),3 to 19 cmH20,5.7 x 5.1 x 3.9 inches,N/A,1.76 pounds,,N/A,,28 dBA,PVA pressure relief included,,Built-in,,Charcoal Gray,2-Year Manufacturer Warranty,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,N/A,N/A,,,
10,Devilbiss IntelliPAP AutoAdjust CPAP Machine with Optional Heated Humidifier,DV54D-HH,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/devilbiss-intellipap-autoadjust-cpap-machine-with-optional-heated-humidifier-p-88.html,E0601/E0562,Optional,,,,,,,"CPAP, APAP",,,26 dB,400 ml,CPAP and Auto CPAP,3cm to 20cm H20 (.5cm increments),0 to 45 minutes (5-min increments),4 to CPAP Pressure (User adjustable),6.5 x 8.4 x 6.4 inches,6.4 x 6.5 x 8.4 inches,2.75 lbs,,4.45 lbs,,26 dBA,,,"Built-in, 8 foot power cord included",,"Off White (machine), Blue (humidifier)",5-Year Manufacturer Warranty (CPAP Only),,,"Yes, Battery is available separately",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,N/A,N/A,,,
11,Devilbiss IntelliPAP 2 AutoAdjust CPAP Machine,"DV64D, DV64D-HH, ...",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/devilbiss-intellipap-autoadjust-cpap-machine-p-1017.html,"E0601, E0562",Built-in with free Smartlink App. Bluetooth 2.1 +EDR and Bluetooth 4.0.,,,"On Screen Sleep Progress Reports, IntelliPAP.com, or SmartLink App (Optional)",,,Standard or Pulse Dose Heated Humidifier (Optional),"CPAP, APAP",,,Less than 26.6 dBA,375 ml,CPAP + APAP,3-20cm H2O,0 to 45 Minutes (User Adjustable in 5 Minute Increments),3 to Minimum Therapy Pressure,3.7 x 6.1 x 5.9 inches,6.3 x 6.1 x 7.6 inches,1.93 lbs,,3.8 lbs,,26.6 dBA,,,1.25 lbs,,"Off White (machine only), Blue (humidifier)",Device and Humidifier - 3 years; Water Chamber - 3 months,,100v-240v (50-60Hz),"Yes, Battery is available separately",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"50 meters, direct line of sight",N/A,,,
12,ResMed AirSense 10 AutoSet CPAP for Her with HumidAir,"37209, 37210",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/resmed-airsense-10-autoset-cpap-for-her-with-humidair-p-850.html,E0601/E0562,,,SD Card (Optional) 365 Days of Summary Data,On Screen Sleep Report MyAir Online,,,Built-in,"CPAP, AutoSet/AutoSet for Her",,,26.6 dBA,380 mL to Maximum Fill Line,CPAP and Auto CPAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 minute (@ 5-minute increments),"Auto Ramp with Sleep Detection, Standard Ramp 0 to 45 Minutes - User Adjustable",8 x 4.57 x 5.91 inches (with side cover),4.57 x 10.04 x 5.91 inches,2.452 lbs (with side cover),,2.75 lbs (44 oz.),"EPR (Settings = Off, 1, 2, 3 CM H2O)",26.6 dBA,Yes,Automatic Up To 8500 Feet,,MyAir Online,White with Floral prints,2-Year Manufacturer Warranty,2GB SD Card (Optional),"100-240V, 50-60Hz (Auto Sensing)","Yes, Battery is available separately",Compatible with all standard Cpap masks,Yes,"English, French, Spanish, Portuguese",Yes,Yes,Yes,0 to 45 Minutes (5 Minute Increments),Disposable (Standard & Hypoallergenic Available),,,,Automatic,,,,,,"Off, 1 Minimum to 8 Maximum",,,ClimateControl with optional ClimateLineAir Heated Tubing,,
13,APEX Medical XT Auto CPAP Machine with Heated Humidifier,SC04201,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/apex-medical-xt-auto-cpap-machine-with-heated-humidifier-p-636.html,"E0601, E0562",,Yes,"730 sessions (Summary Data), Efficacy Data (AHI, Leak) 18 sessions ( or cumulative 72 hours )",SD card & USB port for efficacy data retrieval,,,Integrated,"CPAP, APAP",,,28 dBA,300 ml or 10.15 ounce,CPAP and Auto CPAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 min. (5-min. increments),3 to 19 cmH20,10 x 6.8 x 9.5 inches,"Humidifier base: 10 x 6.9 x 1.97 in, Humidifier water chamber: 5.36 x 5.91 x 4.14 in",1.75 pounds (Machine alone),,3.65 lbs,PVA (Pressure Variation Algorithm) Level 1 provides small pressure variation; and level 3 provides higher pressure variation,28 dBA,Optional,"Pressure of 4 -18 cm H20 = Up To 8,000 Feet Pressure of 18.5 - 20 cm H20 = Up To 5,000 Feet",,N/A,Charcoal Gray,2-Year Manufacturer Warranty,"SD Card, Summary Data (730 sessions)",Universal 100v-240v (50-60Hz),N/A,Compatible with all standard Cpap masks,,,,,,0 to 45 cm H2O (5 min increments),Reusable foam filter,,,,Automatic,,,,,,1 (lowest) to 6 (hightest),,,N/A,,
14,APEX Medical iCH II Auto CPAP Machine with Humidifier,SF07109,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/apex-medical-ich-ii-auto-cpap-machine-with-humidifier-p-603.html,E0601/E0562,,Yes,"Onboard data Compliance = 730 sessions; Advanced Data = 18 sessions; 72 hours. Saved data is first in, first out.",Dual Downloading Ports- SD card + USB cable data access,,,"Built-in, 1 (lowest) to 6 (hightest)","CPAP, APAP",,,"Less than 29.2 dBA at 10 cmH2O, 1 metre distance",300 ml or 10.15 ounce,CPAP and Auto CPAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 minute (@ 5-minute increments),"3 cm H2O, Adjustable",6.5 x 7.8 x 6.9 inches,"Water chamber is approximately: 3 1/2 in (W), 5 3/8 in (H), 6 in (L)",2.5 lbs,,"built-in, 2.5 lbs",PVA (Pressure Variation Algorithm) Level 1 provides small pressure variation; and level 3 provides higher pressure variation.,"Less than 29.2 dBA at 10 cmH2O, 1 metre distance",Built-in,"8,000 ft with pressure 4 cm H2O to 18 cm H2O; 5,000 ft with pressure 18.5 cm H2O to 20 cm H2O",,N/A,Charcoal Gray,2-Year Manufacturer Warranty,"SD Card, 730 summary sessions, 18 detailed sessions",Universal 100v-240v (50-60Hz),N/A,Compatible with all standard Cpap masks,,,,,,3.0 to Therapy pressure (0.5 cmH2Oincrement),Reusable foam filter - 5/8 in x 3/4,,,,Yes,,,,,,"1 (lowest) to 6 (hightest), from 40°C-70°C",,,N/A,,
15,Respironics PR System One Auto CPAP Machine & Humidifier For Sale,"DS560TS, DS560HS, ...",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/respironics-system-one-auto-cpap-machine-humidifier-for-sale-p-420.html,"E0601 (APAP), E0562(humidifier)",,,More than 1 Year of Summary Data,SleepMapper App (iPhone & Android) via BlueTooth Limited Compliance Data on Screen Desktop Software Not Available to Consumers,,,,,"100-240 VAC, 50/60 Hz",,,,CPAP and Auto CPAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 minute (@ 5-minute increments),4 to Min Pressure (User adjustable),7 x 5.5 x 4 inches,10.75 x 6.5 x 4 inches,3 lbs,80w = (5.9 lbs) 60w = (5.82 lbs),4.9 lbs,A-Flex,30 dBA,Yes,Automatic Up To 7500 Feet,"60-Watt Power Supply = .9 lbs, 80-Watt Power Supply = 1.2 lbs",Sleepmapper,Charcoal Gray,2-Year Manufacturer Warranty,SD Card,100 - 240v (50/60Hz),Yes,Compatible with all masks,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Optional,
16,HDM Z1 Auto Travel CPAP Machine,"HD60-1007, HD60-1017",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/hdm-z1-auto-travel-cpap-machine-p-934.html,E0601(CPAP)+A7037(Tube)+A7038(Filter),,,30 Days of Storage Onboard,NiteLog App (iOS or Android),,,,,"100-240 VAC, 50/60 Hz",,,,CPAP and Auto CPAP,4 to 20 cm H2O,0 to 45 minute (@ 5-minute increments),4 to Min Pressure (User adjustable),6.48 x 3.30 x 2.02 Inches,N/A,10.4 Ounces,19.9 ounces,N/A,"Z-Breathe with three settings: CPAP 1 = mild relief; CPAP 2 = moderate relief, CPAP 3 = maximum pressure swing relief",26db,"N/A, Heat Moisture Exchanger (HME) Included for Optional Use",Automatic Up To 8000 Feet,9.5 ounces,NiteLog App,Black and Grey,Device - 3 Years; Overnight Battery - 9 months; PowerShell - 2 years; Power Supply - 2 years,"30 Days of Storage Onboard, built-in BlueTooth",Universal 100v-240v (50-60Hz),"Yes, PowerShell Optional",Compatible with all standard Cpap masks,,English,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,N/A,
17,Fisher & Paykel ICON+ Auto CPAP Machine with Built In Heated Humidifier & SensAwake,"ICONAAN-HT, ICONAAN",https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/fisher-paykel-icon-auto-cpap-machine-with-built-heated-humidifier-sensawake-p-203.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18,Transcend Auto Portable CPAP with EZEX Pressure Relief,503065,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/transcend-auto-portable-cpap-with-ezex-pressure-relief-p-604.html,E0601,,,"Total Blower Hours, 13 Months Daily Compliance Storage","AHI and Leak Detect, Total Therapy Hours, Therapy Sessions greater than or equal to 8-6-4 Hours",,,,,"100 to 240 AC , 50 - 60 Hz, 2.0-1.0 A",,,,CPAP + APAP,4cm to 20cm H2O (1cm Increments),0 to 45 min. (5-min. increments),"Off, 4 to Min Pressure (User adjustable)",6.10 x 3.5 x 2.79 inches,N/A,0.94 lbs,1.59 lbs,N/A,"EZEX Pressure Relief (Settings OFF, 1, 2, 3)",26.6 dBA,Optional,Auto,No,No,Gray,2 Years,Transfer via usb with Transcend Software,Universal 100v-240v (50-60Hz),"Yes, Battery is available separately",Compatible with all masks,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Overnight = 5 hrs. Multi-night = 8 hrs.,Overnight Battery = 6-8 hrs. Multi-night = 14-16 hrs. (Depending on pressure settings)
19,ResMed AirStart 10 Auto CPAP w/ Humidifier,37202,https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/auto-cpap/resmed-airstart-10-auto-cpap-humidifier-p-1087.html,E0601,,,,,,,,,,,,,CPAP + APAP,4-20 cmH2O,0-45 (5 min increments),4 to min pressure,"8"" L x 4.57"" W x 5.91"" H","10.04"" L x 4.57"" W x 5.91"" H",Approx 2.45,4.05 lbs,2.75 lbs,EPR,26.6 dBA,Yes,"Auto, Manual",No,,Black/Grey,2 Year Manufacturer Warranty,SD Card - 365 sessions,100v-240v (50-60Hz),90w 24v,Compatible with all masks,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

[image]

Comment: the data frame is obtained correctly with this change. However, I still have one issue, there are only 2 rows printed in my csv file. Is it printing a row for a page? I wanted 1 row for each product

Comment: It's combining all the products from all the pages upto the given page number and at once it's writing to the csv

Comment: For page 1, I have 20 rows

Comment: i am still not getting the output. Could you check the code you have given please?

Comment: It's running fine in my system

Comment: @huy I have added image as well

Comment: i think you are also getting only products for one page. I wanted products for multiple pages for eg for this link - https://www.respshop.com/cpap-masks/parts/

Comment: The question said same entries are getting populated again and again. Moreoever, according to the url, it's scraped correctly whatever products are there in the page. And it's your code only

Comment: As far as the question is concerned, this answer is correct